# How open alarm function from ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Good afternoon,

I have been searching but I can not find anything, I would like that from my app made with ionic 3, when I click on a button there will be the alarm tool of the mobile device, is it possible?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Check [Ionic Native Local Notifications Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/). It should do the job for you using trigger property passed to schedule method.

example:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';


constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) { }

...

    // Schedule delayed notification
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
       text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
       trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
       led: 'FF0000',
       sound: null
    });
```

Check [Plugin Repo](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) for the full documentation with a full list of available types of triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already tried this plugin but in the background it does not work

Comment: Try using Background Mode plugin to prevent the app from going to sleep while in background. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

Comment: I already tried it too, but I did not fucniono. Do you know if there is any way to go to the cell phone alarm?

Comment: i've searched for something like that but unfortunately i haven't found anything useful.